# EXC_BAD_ACCESS In Sending Mail With Attachement in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have create program to send mail with my some detail from sqlite database

It is working fine if I am not using attachment but if i uncomment that like i m getting exception like this:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x474e5091
```

here is My code:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailView = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    mailView.mailComposeDelegate = (id) self;

    NSArray *recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"chintan_zwt@yahoo.com"];

    [mailView setToRecipients:recipients];
    [mailView setSubject:@"Try Mail From User Application"];

    NSString *body = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"First Name : %@ <br>",lblFirstName.text];

    body = [body stringByAppendingFormat:@"Last Name : %@<br>",lblLastName.text];
    body = [body stringByAppendingFormat:@"Username  : %@<br>",lblUsername.text];
    body = [body stringByAppendingFormat:@"Password  : %@<br>",lblPassword.text];
    body = [body stringByAppendingFormat:@"Birthdate : %@<br>",lblBD.text];

    [mailView addAttachmentData:[UIImagePNGRepresentation(u.Img1) bytes]
                       mimeType:@"image/png"
                       fileName:@"a.png"];

    [mailView setMessageBody:body isHTML:YES];

    [self presentModalViewController:mailView animated:YES];
```

I m getting data correctly from database and i m able to display image on screen but problem is only when i attach image to mail

Here in

```
UIImagePNGRepresentation(u.Img1)
```

U is an object of User Class (user define class) and Img1 is object of UIImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of the [`addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008200-CH1-SW2) method need a `NSData` object, so there is not need o call the bytes method on the `NSData`.

If you try this in you code you can check wether the [`UIImagePNGRepresentation()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImagePNGRepresentation) method returns a valid NSData object. Just place a breakpoint on the line and check what the values are in the debugger.

```
NSData *imageDate = UIImagePNGRepresentation(u.Img1);
[mailView addAttachmentData:imageDate mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"a.png"];
```